# Create zip of the source code in gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to create a zip of my entire code base using a gradle task. I am facing one issue to get the parentDir . I have tried using project , project.rootDir, project.rootProject, projectDir, project, sourceSets*.allSource . I am not getting any correct output. I f I use project alone, it gives me a zip containing only the subproject files. Any pointers?
 My task looks like this :

```
task srcZip(type:Zip){
from project
exclude('**/*//*.iml', '*//*build/', '*//*dist')
exclude('*.zip')
destinationDir file('dist')
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are configuring this task in a subproject instead of the root build.gradle?

Comment: No, I can try in the root build.gradle . I ll try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build my source code zip from the root with a list of projects like so:

```
from ('./') {
    include ([':proja',':projb',...].collect {
        relativePath(project(it).projectDir) + '/' 
    })
}
```

It lets me select a sub-set of projects to archive. Don't forget to filter out some temp dirs like `build/` and `.gradle/`.

`relativePath(project.rootDir)` or `relativePath(rootProject.projectDir)` should give you access to the top of your multi-project repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the task in your root project build.gradle, you can do the following:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    subprojects.each { project ->
        from project.sourceSets.main.allSource
    }
    exclude('**/*//*.iml', '*//*build/', '*//*dist')
    exclude('*.zip')
    destinationDir file("dist")
    baseName = "sourcecode"
}
```

This code assumes a few things:

1) All of your subprojects have source sets. If this is not the case, you will have to add a check.

2) There is no source code in the root project. If there is, and you wish to add it, you can add the following line:

```
from project.sourceSets.main.allSource
```

Answer (score 0):

project.parent.projectDir worked for me . Initially when I used it, the task wouldn't stop and keep executing without giving any results but I tried in another system, it worked. Thanks for all the reponses but I think this is the perfect solution for me.